# Can I get milliseconds date value from a datepicker? (the milliseconds since 1970 value)

Tags: android, datepicker

I have a DatePicker d; and I need to get the milliseconds value of the date. (the milliseconds since 1970 value)

how can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a calender object and set the date and time from the date picker and today.getTimeInMillis().

```
onDateSet(...) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(...);
    long mills = c.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

Comment: I would also call `c.setTimeInMillis(0);` just below getInstance() to set hours, minutes, seconds to 0

Answer (score 2):

You just have to convert your result, using [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), or, more easily, [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net)

Here is an example with Joda-Time :

```
DateMidnight d = new DateMidnight(picker.getYear(), picker.getMonth(), picker.getDayOfMonth());
long millis = d.toDate().getTime();
```

Comment: what is DateMidnight?