# How to get milliseconds from a date picker?

Tags: java, android

In my project I am saving milliseconds in a sqllite databse, by default I am saving

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

in the database, but there is an option for the user to select previous date from a date picker? But what sould I save then when user selects a previous or up comming days from the date picker? How can I get that day as a long(milliseconds) format?

Comment: [This helps you lot](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/05/date-and-time-picker-views-android.html)

Comment: Do you mean how to get the time in millis from a date object? Cause that's just the .getTime() method of the date class...

Comment: No when I will change the date from date picket then i want to get that date in milliseconds.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a `Calender` instance and set the date you want. Then call `calendar.getTimeInMillis();`. See the answer of [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431172/can-i-get-miliseconds-date-value-from-a-datepicker-the-miliseconds-since-1970) for more information.

**EDIT** To set the calendar date you can use something like this:

```
//Lets suppose you have a DatePicker instance called datePicker
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());
```

See the [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class for more information.

Comment: I saw the answer but I am unable to find what should I write in the
onDateSet(...) ?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a similar solution for a javase scenario when I came across this answer. I made a little modification to **Angelo's answer** to make my own case work, and it gave me exactly what I was looking for. To make things a little more interesting, I created a method that can be reused.

```
class Controller {

    public static Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    public static long getEpoch_fromDatePicker( DatePicker datePicker ) {

        Controller.cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getValue().getDayOfMonth() );
        Controller.cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getValue().getMonthValue() );
        Controller.cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getValue().getYear() );

        return Controller.cal.getTimeInMillis() /1000;
    }
}
```

Someone might find this useful