# Time in milliseconds from time and date picker

Tags: java, android, datepicker, timestamp, datetimepicker

I'm working on an app in which I'm getting date and time from date and time picker dialog. I need to convert it into milliseconds in long value and upload to the server.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

first u create calender with values from date and time picker

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth(), 
             timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 1):

As already answered here: [how to get milliseconds from a date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11430439/6067892)

Just create a calendar and get time in millis

```
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(this);
TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker(this);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

long millis = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this

Comment: check the edit, I fix the picker

Comment: Using Joda or (if available) Java 8 time is nearly always a cleaner solution.

Comment: `java.time` was introduced in Java 8 alright, but *is* available for lower API level Android through [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), the Android edition of the backport.

Answer (score 0):

Override TimePickerDialog.onTimeChanged(). It will be called once the selected time changes. You can then cinvert the result to millseconds by doing some simple maths.