# Storing multiple variables into one variable - Java

Tags: java, android, variables

So I am having trouble assigning multiple variables to one variable.

I have a date picker and time picker in my application and the values that the user picks are stored as separate variables. I then want to take all of the variables and assign them to one variable so I can store the users input and use it publicly in other activities.

EDIT:
so I am working with a third party library that uses animated graphs and to generate the graph I must pass through integers. So after trying out all your suggestions this it is working using the Gregorian way:

```
timeselected = new GregorianCalendar(yearNow, monthNow, dayNow, hourNow, minuteNow).getTime();
```

Only thing now is this is stored as a date and cannot be cast to an integer??

For example, here is what I have tried so far:

The variables that I use to store the picker selection are:

```
 int dayNow, monthNow, yearNow, hourNow, minuteNow;
```

I have tried to assign them to one variable like so:

```
timeselected = (yearNow) + (monthNow) + (dayNow) + (hourNow) + (minuteNow);
```

Although this is giving me a total of all the variables added up. e.g. year(2017) plus month(11) etc.

Does anyone know how I can get this to store the selected data (which should be a date format) as an Integer?

Thanks

Comment: This past answer might help.  But you can use the java.time framework and bring in your values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499228/creating-java-date-object-from-year-month-day

Comment: You can convert it to timestamp See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777317/convert-java-util-date-default-format-to-timestamp-in-java

Comment: Because all of the variables are int, they getting added as integer. Please use this it should solve ur problem. Timeselected = “” + yearNow + monthNow+ ...

Comment: just convert to timestamp using Calendar object

Comment: Whats the prob dude ?  Just Use [Calender](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class .

Comment: @NabinBhandari this is giving me a red line and wants me to change it to type string. Could anyone provide me code on how to convert to timestamp or to use calendar class?

Comment: Can you use `long` instead of `int` in that library? Also provide sample input and expected output for your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to describe in a comment, but I think this is what you are looking for (I assume you are looking for the format yyyymmddhhmm):

Take the suggestion from **Nabin Bhandari**:

```
String sTimeselected = ""+(yearNow) + (monthNow) + (dayNow) + (hourNow) + (minuteNow);
```

And simply convert to `long` with:

```
long timeselected = Long.parseLong(sTimeselected);
```

If this isn't it than I am still unclear as to what you need.

**EDIT::**
For any integer values which you need to have at least 2 digits (eg. 2 => 02) then you can format the `int` to a string like this:

```
String sDay = String.format("%02d", dayNow);
```

Comment: It seems to be all fine. although my app is crashing with this error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20171131524"

Comment: okay ill try that, do I have to do that for each variable? year month etc

Comment: Integer cannot hold 12 digits.

Comment: @NabinBhandari :: Correct I have edited my answer. That is what happens when I don't 'debug' my own solution! `int` allows a maximum value of 2147483647 -- a factor of 10 less then 20171131524.

Comment: thanks guys this is working now just the format is still as a long number. my library also accepts a long!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int dayNow=3, monthNow=11, yearNow=2017, hourNow=9, minuteNow=20;
Date timeselected = new GregorianCalendar(yearNow, monthNow-1, dayNow, hourNow, minuteNow).getTime();
System.out.println(timeselected );
```

Comment: I do not want to hardcode the values. the variables are dependent on what the user selects from the date and time pickers

Comment: This answer is not meant to be a direct copy/paste into your project - it just shows how to take ints and get a full date. You need to modify to fit your needs.

Comment: @TheAlmac2 Instead of hard coded values, assign user input value to dayNow, monthNow etc.

Comment: tried this method. although I am passing this as an integer through a calculation and therefore it must be an integer. this method sets it as a date which Is not accepted by the calculation method

Comment: @TheAlmac2 :: You did not mention any calculations in your OP. You only stated "store the users input and use it publicly in other activities" . Perhaps you should edit your OP and explain more clearly what you will be doing with the "date" you wish to generate.

Answer (score 0):

Use epoch counter.

First, a bit of history: if you try to print the value of a

```
System.getCurrentMillis();
```

call, you'll notice that will print something like `1509719045`. These are milliseconds from Jan 01 1970, date where this count has started.

To answer your question, i would read [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4431249/1489346).

Now you not only have your single integer variable which stores your entire date and time, but you can even convert it back to Date or Calendar easily.